# jquery function call multiple times on class name need to prevent

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i need to call js function on **LIST ITEM** click but when event fires it calls the event  number of times

**JS**

```
$('.first').click(function () {

    //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
    items.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show();

    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="v-nav">
                <ul>

                    <li tab="tab1" class=" first CmclTabCss  current "> <span class="spn_InerCom"> Commercial Sector </span> <span class="tab1Current spn_Nmbr"> </span></li>
                    <li tab="tab2" class="first DMTabCss"><span class="spn_InerDip">Diplomatic Missions</span><span class="tab1CurrentD spn_Nmbr"></span></li>
                    <li tab="tab3" class="first GovTabCss"><span class="spn_InerGov">Government Sector</span><span class="tab1CurrentG spn_Nmbr"></span></li>
                    <li tab="tab4" class="first WrldTabCss"><span class="spn_InerWld">Outside Kingdom</span><span class="tab1CurrentW spn_Nmbr"> </span></li>
                    <li tab="tab5" class="first ImgTabCss"><span class="spn_InerImg">Images</span><span class="tab1CurrentI spn_Nmbr"> </span></li>
                    <li tab="tab6" class="first"><span class="spn_InerNews">News Archive</span><span class="tab1CurrentN spn_Nmbr"> </span></li>

                    <li tab="tab7" class="first PplTabCss"><span class="spn_InerIndual">Site Users</span><span class="tab1CurrentIndual spn_Nmbr"></span></li>

                </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "it calls the event number of times" Should work as here: http://jsfiddle.net/JkvWF/

Comment: I see no reason why the code shown would cause that click handler to be called more than once per click (and indeed it isn't in a [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpAeW/)). The problem could be in your _other_ code (you obviously haven't shown all of your code since the above refers to a variable not declared or set there).

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is correct. Check it out here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxAdH/)

There must be other part of your code that triggers the `click` handler multiple times.

For the problem described this code does the job (omitted your specific code for clarity):

```
$('.first').click(function () {
    $('.first').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
});
```